# dilation and erosion on red green and blue channels to remove a particular structure and then combine channels to form an rgb image

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

i am working on an image in opencv python to remove vessels from an image by taking the red, green, and blue channels of an image and then applying dilation followed by erosion on each channel..when i am combining those channels i am also getting a green blob on the image.can anybody please help me in sorting out why i am getting this green blob on my image after combining the 3 channels?
here is my code:

```
# imports
import cv2 
from skimage.morphology import erosion, dilation, opening, closing, white_tophat
from skimage.morphology import disk

circle = disk(10)
# =====  blue =====
# import the picture
img_array = cv2.imread('im0006.ppm')
# note that [:,:,0] is blue, [:,:,1] is green, [:,:,2] is red
img_array[:,:,1] = 0
img_array[:,:,2] = 0
# write the image
cv2.imwrite('b.jpg',img_array) #blue channel image

# ===== green =====

img_array = cv2.imread('im0006.ppm') 
img_array[:,:,0] = 0
img_array[:,:,2] = 0
cv2.imwrite('g.jpg', img_array)

# ===== red =====
img_array = cv2.imread('im0006.ppm')
img_array[:,:,0] = 0
img_array[:,:,1] = 0
cv2.imwrite('r.jpg', img_array)

#############operation on blue channel###########
image=cv2.imread('b.jpg')
#cv2.imshow('ero',image)

dilation = cv2.dilate(image,circle,iterations = 1)
eroded = cv2.erode(dilation,circle,iterations = 1)
cv2.imshow('eroded_blue',eroded)

#############operation on green channel###########
image1=cv2.imread('g.jpg')
#cv2.imshow('ero1',image1)
cir = disk(12)
#element = cv2.getStructuringElement(circle,(7,7) )
dilation1 = cv2.dilate(image1,cir,iterations = 1)
eroded1 = cv2.erode(dilation1,cir,iterations = 1)
cv2.imshow('eroded_green',eroded1)
cv2.imwrite('veinless_g.jpg',eroded1)

#############operation on red channel###########
image2=cv2.imread('r.jpg')
#cv2.imshow('ero2',image1)
dilation2 = cv2.dilate(image2,circle,iterations = 1)
eroded2 = cv2.erode(dilation2,circle,iterations = 1)
cv2.imshow('eroded_red',eroded2)

result=eroded+eroded1+eroded2
cv2.imshow('result',result)
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You might want to show your input and output images. Also, why is the blue image processing different from red and green? Are the g.jpg, r.jpg and b.jpg image fine? Besides, passing through jpg format might be dangerous, as introduces lossy compression and, therefore, artifacts.

Comment: @Antonio..the green channel processing is a little different because  in green channel vessels become more prominent thats why i have used te bigger structuring element for erasing the vessels completely as compared to blue and red. and yes g.jpg,b.jpg and r.jpg are perfectly fine(without any blobs).

Comment: i have also tried to save it with different extension(i.e png) but the problem is still there.

Comment: Why do you add `eroded1 + eroded2 + eroded3`? Why do you not put them in an array in the same way as the original image is constructed? Have you checked the max value of `result`? I think you might be exceeding the maximum value for the data type hence why it's green.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding them unless you have a specific reason for it. It's better to use use a 3D array in my opinion.

Comment: @kkuilla..yes the problem was in addition.thanks for pointing out.